# Autospectrum computation with vDSP_zaspec doesn't work

Tags: swift, spectrum, vdsp

I try to compute the autospectrum of  a recorded signal, I use the function vDSP_zaspec. Normally the output array is real.

```
class  func autoSpectrum (input: [Float])->[Float] {
        
        var real = [Float](input)
        var imaginary = [Float](repeating: 0.0, count : input.count)
        var Output:[Float] = [Float](repeating:0 , count: input.count)
        let length = vDSP_Length(real.count/2)
   
        real.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer {realBP in
                   imaginary.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer {imaginaryBP in
                      
                       var splitComplex = DSPSplitComplex(realp: realBP.baseAddress!, imagp: imaginaryBP.baseAddress!)
                       vDSP_zaspec(&splitComplex, &Output, vDSP_Length(input.count))
                    
                   }
               }
    let value = vDSP.rootMeanSquare(Output)
   Output = vDSP.divide(Output, value)

        return Output
    }
```

I did a test with a 500 Hz sin wave and this is what the Output array looks like :

[image]

The chart is far from the expected result...The result looks like the absolute value of the recorded audio file...

If someone could help me, it will be great !

Answer (score 0):

`vDSP_zaspec` returns the sum of each real part squared and the corresponding imaginary part squared. The [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vdsp/autospectrum_computation) describes it as "Compute the element-wise sum of the squares of the real and imaginary parts of a complex vector".

The following pieces of code calculate the same results:

```
var real: [Float] = [-2, 7, -3]
var imaginary: [Float] = [4, -1, -4]

var vDSPresult: [Float] = [0, 0, 0]
var scalarResult: [Float] = [0, 0, 0]

real.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer {realBP in
    imaginary.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer {imaginaryBP in
        var splitComplex = DSPSplitComplex(realp: realBP.baseAddress!,
                                           imagp: imaginaryBP.baseAddress!)
        vDSP_zaspec(&splitComplex,
                    &vDSPresult,
                    vDSP_Length(vDSPresult.count))
        
    }
}

print(vDSPresult)

for i in 0 ..< scalarResult.count {
    scalarResult[i] = pow(real[i], 2) + pow(imaginary[i], 2)
}

print(scalarResult)
```

Comment: If I understand, VDS_Zaspec calculates only the square of the magnitude of a complex number?...
Prior to vDSP_zaspec I have to calculate the FFT, am I right?
Regarding the Apple documentation, the explanation is confusing....
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Yes, the FFT returns the frequency domain complex vector and `vDSP_zaspec` calculates the autospectrum of that vector.

Comment: Flex Monkey, thanks a lot for your reply.